# Android - Dynamically load content

Tags: java, android, dynamic, scrollable

I have a page in my app where the user can see a news feed (mostly images). How do I display these images (Using a LinearLayout maybe?)? And if so, how do I dynamically increase the size of this scrollable layout as I am scrolling down? (To load more images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). From the doc:

```
A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list.
```

you have to provide a `ListAdapter` to your ListView. Basically the apdater is what fills up the `ListView`. It is higly customizable. You can simply pass  to the adapter your data set or `extend` the adapter and customize the `getView` method in order to get the data rapresentation you want.

a tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out. I was also just looking at ScrollView too. Is that more suitable for images?

Comment: yes it is the correct way to achive what you want. In order to add images/thumbnail you have to extend the BaseAdapter and override the getView method. Search for some good tutorial over the net

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to use listview, just add the content and notify the adapter.